# Getting UIViewRepresentable to run a block just once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I'd like to wrap a CaptureSession in a SwiftUI view. The current way I'm doing this is:

```swift
struct VideoPreviewView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var cameraManager: CameraManager

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if cameraManager.isSessionInitialized {
            print("here")
            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraManager.captureSession)
            previewLayer.frame = uiView.layer.bounds
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            uiView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        }
    }
}
```

Here my CameraManager is initializing the session and sets the isSessionInitialized when it's ready. The issue is the `print("here")` is happening multiple times. I'd only like it to run once. I can't figure out how to only run that code once. I initially thought I could make a property `private var hasRun`, but the struct is immutable so it was useless to update. Then I thought I could do it with `@State`, but you're not allowed to update state during a view update, so that was also useless.

Ideally, I'd be able to put all the view/layer stuff in `makeUIView` and conditionally create this view, like so:

```swift
struct VideoPreviewView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var cameraManager: CameraManager

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraManager.captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

And have a loading screen in my `ContentView` where I initialize it:

```swift
if cameraManager.isSessionInitialized {
    VideoPreviewView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
} else {
    Text("loading cam")
}
```

(rather than just `VideoPreviewView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` in the `ContentView`).

But this doesn't work. It just shows a blank screen where the video preview should be. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jasoneveleth/4fa2faced568cb1dbd2da296e8f50e88) for the modified code with the whole thing in case it would be easiest to test it out in XCode yourself.

So, can anyone help me figure out how to get the `print("here")` to only run once?

EDIT (irrelevant since we found the answer):

Here are two potential fixes, both of which don't seem to quite work.

First one:

```swift
// ContentView
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VideoPreviewView(cameraManager: cameraManager).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        RecordButton()
    }
    .environmentObject(cameraManager)
}
```

and

```swift
struct VideoPreviewView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let cameraManager: CameraManager
    
    init(cameraManager: CameraManager) {
        self.cameraManager = cameraManager
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if cameraManager.isSessionInitialized {
            print("now")
            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraManager.captureSession)
            previewLayer.frame = uiView.layer.bounds
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            uiView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work (the view is still blank) and the "now" print statement doesn't fire. The second interpretation of the comment is:

```swift
// ContentView
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if cameraManager.isSessionInitialized {
            VideoPreviewView(cameraManager: cameraManager).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else {
            Text("nope not in this house")
        }
        RecordButton()
    }
    .environmentObject(cameraManager)
}
```

and

```swift
struct VideoPreviewView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let cameraManager: CameraManager
    
    init(cameraManager: CameraManager) {
        self.cameraManager = cameraManager
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        if cameraManager.isSessionInitialized {
            print("now")
            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraManager.captureSession)
            previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

The "now" print statement fires, but it's still a blank screen.

Comment: Check the frame size of the view, maybe it's zero.

Comment: Remove the environment object wrapper just use a “let”

Comment: @loremipsum I can't remove the environment object wrapper since I'm initializing it higher up in the view hierarchy. I need to do that since the recording button also needs to access the CameraManager. See my [gist](https://gist.github.com/jasoneveleth/4fa2faced568cb1dbd2da296e8f50e88).

Comment: Pass it as a “let” from the parent from the View that has the conditional. You are just removing the wrapper that is what triggers update

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll try that. (I am new to SwiftUI, so apologies) @loremipsum

Comment: @loremipsum I tried that (new code in the gist), but it didn't work or I didn't understand what I needed to fix. I think the problem with it was now there's no update at all (and we need one for when the CameraManager sets it's state to initialized), so the camera is never set up. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Possibly, I don’t look at gist’s from SO, others might. SO questions should be all inclusive and concise so others can benefit from them. People like me answer questions here to help the many.

Comment: @loremipsum fair. I was trying to keep the question concise by having the rest of the code in the gist (the whole app is 110 lines). But, I have attached my two interpretations of your comment as edits to the question. Let me know if I misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: We don’t need the whole app SO has a term MRE, Minimal Reproducible Example, it comes up to the least amount of code to reproduce your issue, SwiftUI makes it so easy that anyone should be able to copy and paste your code and see the issue.

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you for spending the time to help me, I really appreciate it. I hope my example is minimal (I have a much larger/more complex app that this behavior and the mini app in the gist is taken from). I have put my two interpretations of the comment "Pass it as a “let” from the parent..." as an edit to the question. Is one of them what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
struct VideoPreviewView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var cameraManager: CameraManager

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if cameraManager.isSessionInitialized && shouldInit(in: uiView) {
            print("here")
            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraManager.captureSession)
            previewLayer.frame = uiView.layer.bounds
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            uiView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        }
    }
    
    private func shouldInit(in uiView: UIView) -> Bool {
        guard let sublayers = uiView.layer.sublayers, !sublayers.isEmpty else {
            return true
        }
        return !sublayers.contains { layer in
            layer is AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        }
    }
}
```

In order not to add the layer if it's already present.

Answer (score 0):

The issue as @vadian pointed out is the bounds were zero since I the view I was taking the bounds from was just initialized. The correct code is a tiny change from my desired modifications. Use `UIScreen.main.bounds` rather than `view.layer.bounds`.